# a lisp function to toggle a mode (org mode in this case) on and off with a single shortcut

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to create a shortcut (C-c c)
regardless of what kind of file is currently opened
(it could be a .pl file or a .txt file or an extension less file)
pressing C-c c should turn on org mode if its not turned on already.
pressing it again and again toggles it off and on....

Here's what I have

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c c") (lambda () (interactive)
  (org-mode))))
```

Any help?
It's important that when turning off org mode, whatever the "native" mode the file was originally on comes back on.

Comment: The canonical "toggle" in Elisp is called a minor mode, so you can use `define-minor-mode` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work on a few examples I have tried:

```el
(defvar-local last-mode nil
  "Buffer-local variable to store last mode in.")

(defun toggle-org-mode ()
  "Toggle the mode between the current mode and `org-mode'."
  (interactive)
  (make-local-variable 'last-mode)
  (put 'last-mode 'permanent-local t)
  (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
      (progn
        (message "switch back to %s" last-mode)
        (funcall last-mode)
        (setq last-mode nil))
    ;; This means you are in the native mode you started in and now want to
    ;; switch to org-mode
    (message "switch to org from %s" major-mode)
    (setq last-mode major-mode)
    (org-mode)))
```

This is more subtle than it seemed. You have to mark the buffer-local variable as permanent, or it can get wiped out by changing the major mode.

Comment: ahh my neighbor from ucla!

Comment: This does not work: what happens if I have two buffers (different major modes), call the function in the first buffer, call it in the second buffer and then call it again in the first buffer? Maybe making last-mode buffer-local might work.

Comment: that is a good catch. I have modified the solution to make last-mode buffer local.

Comment: I had to comment out the defvar statements, otherwise I got 'Symbol’s function definition is void: nil' when reverting.  I believe the value of last-mode is nil

Comment: see the new edit. It is trickier than I thought to use local variables.

Comment: If you simply want the default mode for the buffer, call `(normal-mode)`.  Something like: `(if (derived-mode-p 'org-mode) (normal-mode) (org-mode))`.

Comment: @phils would that work in message-mode or a non-file buffer?

Comment: Most likely not in the way you want it to in all situations, but it depends somewhat on how one is defining the (question's) phrase "native mode".